# Google Sheets search value and return certain columns of multiple rows where the value is present

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking for a formula which can do the following:
Lookup a value in column E:I and return all the values from column B:D from the rows it is present. 
Example: Looking for `S190202`, it would return B:D from row 2,5,6

[image: Data set]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A1:I, "select B,C,D where E='S190202'
                              or F='S190202'
                              or G='S190202'
                              or H='S190202'
                              or I='S190202'", 1)
```

for a cell reference, you can change it to:

```
=QUERY(A1:I, "select B,C,D where E matches '"&K2&"'
                              or F matches '"&K2&"'
                              or G matches '"&K2&"'
                              or H matches '"&K2&"'
                              or I matches '"&K2&"'", 1)
```

where **K2** contains value `S190202`

Comment: I didn't know I can run query in Google Sheets! Great stuff, thanks! :)