# Search another google spreadsheet's sheet for A1 Value of current sheet, return column A,B,C's value in rows where A1 Value is found

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm trying to query a value located in A1 of a current google spreadsheet, on a sheet located on another spreadsheet and return the values in columns A, B & C for every row where A1's value is found.

I'm dizzy.

I tried this:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXX/edit","Master Investor List!A11:AX"),"select A,B,C where R or U or X matches '"&A1&"',1)
```

but I get this error:

> Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "R "" at line 1, column 20. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you open up a Spreadsheet with openById the active sheet is always `Spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];` So assuming that you have permission to open the other spreadsheet then you'll will have to have to get specific sheets some other means than looking for the active sheet because the active sheets will always be the left most sheet.

Comment: the importrange specifies on which sheet (Master Investor List) to search for A1. I'm not opening the other spreadsheet, I'm just pulling data from it.

Comment: how much rows you have?

Comment: See image, that's the whole sheet what you see.  But I want it to search A1:AX for every instance of A1 on the Current Sheet.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want to do, but pull data from another spreadsheet:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119257/google-sheets-search-value-and-return-certain-columns-of-multiple-rows-where-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url_here"; "Master Investor List!A11:AX")}; 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3 
  where Col18 matches '"&A1&"'
     or Col21 matches '"&A1&"' 
     or Col24 matches '"&A1&"'"; 1)
```

Comment: Tried it, see the images I added to the OP

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: DUDE!!!!!  IT WORKED hahaha.  That was like 6 hours of my day.  You're a genuis, thank you!!!