# Search for a value in multiple columns and return value from Column A

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, flatten

Sheet Example:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jonas | 1 | 6 | 11 | 16 | 21 |
| Joaquin | 2 | 7 | 12 | 17 | 22 |
| William | 3 | 8 | 13 | 18 | 23 |
| Mark | 4 | 9 | 14 | 19 | 24 |
| Stuart | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 |

Search value example:

```
19
```

Expected Return:

```
Mark
```

Formula indicated:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55119579/11462274

```
=QUERY(Clients!A1:F, "select A where B="&B1&"
                              or C="&B1&"
                              or D="&B1&"
                              or E="&B1&"
                              or F="&B1&"", 1)
```

But the result is:

```
Jonas
Stuart
```

Why is `Jonas` returning when there is no value `19` in row `1`?

An additional info:

If I have Columns from `B` to `CC` with values, is this still the indicated method? I ask because of the immense amount of lines I would have to write one by one for each of these columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(B1:F5=I1, A1:A5, )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `INDEX(MATCH())` formula.

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(19,B4:F4,0))
```

[image]